# SQL Server : SELECT last Friday 12 PM to this Friday 12 PM

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to get all records submitted to SQL Server from last Friday 12PM to this Friday 12PM for the purposes of payroll. I have the past 7 days working as shown below but I need it to be specific to 12PM last Friday to 12PM this Friday.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    notifications.requestid,
    Max(timestatuschange),
    assignedtouser,
    Count(requestid) AS Total
FROM   
    notifications
WHERE  
    timestatuschange >= Dateadd(day, -7, Getdate())
    AND notifications.status = 'Yellow'
    OR timestatuschange >= Dateadd(day, -7, Getdate())
    AND notifications.status = 'Red'
    OR timestatuschange >= Dateadd(day, -7, Getdate())
    AND notifications.status = 'Blue'
GROUP BY 
    requestid,
    assignedtouser
```

Comment: which version of sql server are you using?

Comment: please define last friday and this friday.  by this friday do you mean today if it is firday and some point in the future if it not friday?

Comment: your `WHERE` clause is confusing. when using both `AND` and `OR`, always use `(` and `)` to denote precedence. Based on your query, you can use `IN` instead of multiple `OR`

Comment: @ughai thank you the query you posted executed well and it looks at a glance correct I just need to do an audit to make sure.   I will look into IN today as well as studying your query to learn from it.  Thanks so much!

Comment: look up "floor datetime" and then always use `WHERE column >=startdatetime and column<enddatetime` where enddatetime is the date after your end date with no time (12:00:00.000 am)

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using `GETDATE()`, I am assuming today is Friday, you can try something like this

```
SELECT DATEADD(hour,12,CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(),112)),
DATEADD(day,-7,DATEADD(hour,12,CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(),112)))
```

Your query would be

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME = DATEADD(day,-7,DATEADD(hour,12,CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(),112)))

DECLARE @EndDate DATETIME = DATEADD(hour,12,CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(),112))

SELECT DISTINCT notifications.requestid,
                Max(timestatuschange),
                assignedtouser,
                Count(requestid) AS Total
FROM   notifications
WHERE  timestatuschange >=  @StartDate
       AND  timestatuschange <= @EndDate
       AND notifications.status IN ('Yellow','Red','Blue')
GROUP  BY requestid,
          assignedtouser
```

Comment: I mean today is Friday which is when the payroll person needs to review the list sometime after noon the cutoff time.

Comment: The edited SQL also executes nicely but gives 2 extra records over the previous SQL for some reason.  Once I complete an audit I might understand why.